# android backup with adobe air

Tags: android, air, backup

Lets assume I have a phone with Android and some applications installed on it. And I make a backup to cloud using my google account id. Then I broke my phone, and buying a new one with Android. I'm assosiating it with my google account id.

1)Is it mean that all my programs will be restored on my new phone??
2)If I have no google account id - how devices can be associated?
3)How can I make application backup with Adobe AIR SDK for Android?
4)If I make backup of my phone - is MAC address saved too?

Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if backup-restore is available and could be utilized to 
pre-seving game status/data;

We can't backup/restore application on Android with Adobe AIR, but we can use 
many 3-part software for backup.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html